# Mule ESB Enterprise Source Code Clarification

Tags: mule, esb, enterprise

Looking for some guidance and clarification here.

For the licensing for the Mule Enterprise ESB, it operates under a Commercial and Proprietary license. Then I see here that one gets "access to source code" for the Enterprise Edition much like the Community Edition.

http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise

1. What does "access to source code" entail?
2. Do I only get this access once I license the ESB?
3. Is the source code publicly available online?
4. Is it "open source" in the classic sense that I can improve, modify
   and commit recommended changes to the source code?
5. Can I do the same with MMC?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you have a paid subscription with access to the MuleSoft Customer Portal, you can download a zip with a bunch of Java classes, settings files, etc which are used in the EE version. I think this is mostly for debugging purposes, or if you want to extend some EE classes in your Mule application. I am pretty sure you can not fork your own Mule EE, or start contributing changes to the EE repository. I have also not seen any downloads for MMC source code. They probably don't want to share it, as it is one of the selling points for the EE license.

Comment: Anton is correct, the source code access is read only.  There are some parts of the platform that are closed source, including MMC and DataMapper.  In addition to the downloadable source zip, the EE sources are available as maven "source jars" through the customer Maven repository.